# Need help to write a translate method in my segment method

Tags: java

I am trying to write a translate method in a segment class. My variables are p1 = x1, y1 and p2 = x2, y2. How can I create a translate method using these two variables?

I wrote my translate method in my Point class as:

```
public void translate(int xmove, int ymove) {
       x += xmove;
       y += ymove;
    }
```

Here my variables are x and y, simple! But for my segment class I am confused and not sure how to put them in the code.

Comment: In my segment class*

Comment: What is a translate method?

Comment: Hey, I am a bit confused about your question. You have a point class with x and y? and you want to translate a point ? to a different location ?

Comment: Well, what your `Segment` class should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a geometric segment, then it ought to be defined in terms of two `Point`s (a line segment) or two `Point`s and a radius (circular segment), or something along those lines.

In that case, it should have some private fields that store the `Point` data. Translating the whole segment just means translating each `Point` in the class.

So if it's a line segment, and you have

```
class Segment {
    Point start;
    Point end;
    //...
}
```

then you'd just need

```
class Segment {
    Point start;
    Point end;

    public void translate(int xmove, int ymove) {
        start.translate(xmove,ymove);
        end.translate(xmove,ymove);
    }
}
```

This is good design because it reuses your `Point` class in defining the `Segment`, and uses `Point` methods to define `Segment` methods.

But it does depend a little on quite what you mean by "segment"...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is what you want, but assuming you would like to translate a segment of 2 points

```
class Segment{ 
     Point point1; 
     Point point2;
     //constructor
     public void translateSegment(int xmove, int ymove){
         point1.translate(xmove,ymove);
         point2.translate(xmove, ymove);
     }
}
```

If you change the method in the point class to private, you will need to do something else. This code is based on the fact that your translate method for a point is public. There are advantages and disadvantages to having an object mutable, and this is a design question you should consider.